# What to use to switch AC power supply using 5v micro controller?

Tags: relay, mains, solid-state-relay, triac, scr

Here is my question and situation in more details.

I am working on a college project where I need to switch on/off AC appliances using 5v Micro Controller. Appliances can be fan, motor, Fridge, Air Conditioner, in short any high range device possible in house hold.

I've used Relays for this before, but they are bulk and produce noise while switching.

Here is my question broken in to small pieces:

1. Looking at these high power devices like Motors, Air Conditioner and Fridge. **What should be the max number Amps supported by my circuit?**
2. Considering above requirement of amps, **which electronic component should be be used to switch AC power supply?** For example I've used Relays before. But want to the best possible option among TRIAC, SCR's and others.

If there are multiple option for this, please explain with pros and cons. Considering that we need to use this in house hold and should have reliability of production level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [solid state relay.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_relay) They work exactly like regular relays except they are solid state so they don't have switching noise (sound). They are also a bit smaller. Unfortunately, they are typically more expensive than mechanical relays.

There are other options, such as using high power IGBTs or FETs. They aren't as easy to use, but they can switch much faster. For your application, switching speed isn't very critical since you are dealing with fans and refrigerators.

Something like [this](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/AQA221VL/255-2978-ND/2364683) should work well. It needs to be able to handle at least the 15A that is standard in most homes, plus additional peak loads to inrush current to motors and power supplies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with your point that SSR's are expensive and they are hard to find as well. Why shouldn't I use TRAIC or SCRs?

Comment: As I can see by your SSR suggestion part, I should assume max 15A load current?

Comment: 15A maximum would be reasonable as anything larger would trigger a circuit breaker. A few hundred amps peak would be desirable for inrush currents

Comment: You could go with less if you know how much current your load will draw but the SSR might fail if you connect it to a different load.

Comment: Most SSR have some type of thyristor, triac, or scr inside that does the actual switching. The difference being that a SSR is packaged up nice and easy to use just like a relay.

Comment: I've this SCR TYN612M, I got this pretty cheap. Is there any drawback using this one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32574/discussion-between-ishan-dhingra-and-robert-stiffler).